# What does the word "blinkerdom" mean?

Tags: meaning

There's some [context](http://wordincontext.com/en/blinkerdom):

> In this direction M. Loisy has done noble and excellent work; but the dead weight and selfish **blinkerdom** of the Catholic organization has hampered him to that degree that he has been unable to get justice done to his liberalizing designs or, perhaps, even to reveal the full extent of them. And the same difficulty will remain.

Is it a synonym for "blindness"?

Comment: _Tunnel vision_ is an accepted metaphor. I'm not sure that 'blinkerdom' has achieved word status as yet.

Comment: *blinkerdom* is not a word. It's a contextual nonce here.

Comment: @Kris I can’t find “nonce” defined anywhere as a noun that would fit your statement, only as an adjective commonly attached to the noun “word”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blindness, tunnel vision, or more loosely a hostility to non-traditional ideas. The reference is to [blinkers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinkers#Noun), a kind of headgear worn by racing horses that keeps them from seeing anywhere except straight ahead.

Comment: -1 *blinkerdom* is not a word.

Comment: +1 for apt explanation of this nonce word. Might be worth including a bit about highly [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)) suffixes employed by native speakers for ad-hoc nominalization, and/or the specific shift in meaning that _[-dom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-dom#Suffix)_ applies to words.